# Win8.1 Bad Virtual Memory Managment?

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, swap, virtual-memory

For the last couple weeks I'm facing a serious problem with my Win 8.1 32bit (64x CPU) 4G RAM, having "System Managed size" setting for virtual memory (then win allocates 1.8G), minimizing even light weight applications for couple seconds, even when currently running applications are only one or two (and most of the RAM is free), restoring process is very slow, what means that win flashed it's allocated memory to the swap file, it's very strange behaviour that I didn't faced before on any other windows versions.

To check if there is other reasons for that, I disabled virtual memory completely, then everything goes OK, also setting the VMem size manually to like 800M fixes the problem partly, also making a fresh win setup couses same problems, thus I conclude that there is something wrong with new windows virtual memory management system (or I'm doing something wrong), anybody have the clue for the reason of this issue or how to fix that? (I need VMem anyway)

Comment: follow this and give me the result file: http://pastebin.com/yLvYak6n

Comment: Are you allowing your hard drive to sleep?